# Wireshark/Tshark. Very little (data) packets in monitor mode

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, kali-linux, network-monitoring

I'm trying to setup a proof of concept for indoor positioning using `WIFI`. The idea is to place a few `WIFI` adapters in several locations in a small building, each tracking signal strength and `MAC` address and storing it in a database. Based on the signal strength to different adapters at the same time, we can get an (in)accurate position of the device (`MAC`).

There are two `SSIDs` in the building, both with `WPA-PWD` encryption. There will also be devices that are not associated with the network. Since I don't want to install 3 adapters on each location (one for each network) I want to get the signal strength in monitor mode and only switch the channel between the two `SSIDs`.

Using `Kali` and `tshark` i'm able to capture the signal strength using:

```
tshark -i mon0 -T fields -e wlan.sa -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal
```

The problem however is that I receive very little data from my test device (android phone). If I open the `WIFI` manager and it start scanning for networks in the area I capture the broadcast packets, but no other data at all.
I suspected it to be because of the `WPA` encryption and changed to an open network and it worked. I see a constant stream of packets from my android phone.

I turned back to the `WPA` network and setup `tshark` using decryption

```
tshark -i mon0 -o wlan.enable_decryption:TRUE -o "uat:80211_keys:\"wpa-pwd\",\"Passphrase:SSID\""
```

I disconnected my phone from the network, enabled monitor mode and then reconnected the device, to make sure I received the `four-way handshake`. Now I do receive some data packets, but nowhere near the amount I'm actually sending/downloading. At moments I receive about 10 a minute and then nothing at all for a few minutes.

I tried with the folowing setups

- `Kali linux` in `VMWare` on windows 10, with an `ALFA AWUS036H` (RT8187 chipset)

  - I dont receive any data packets from `WPA` protected networks
- `Kali linux ARM` on `Raspberry Pi 3 model b`, same USB adapter

  - I dont receive any data packets from `WPA` protected networks
- `Kali linux` live boot USB, `Qualcomm Atheros AR938x` adapter

  - I receive a few datapackets from `WPA` protected networks

My questions:

1. Is decrypting necessary if I only want `MAC` and signal strength?
2. Why don't I receive most of the data packets being sent?
3. Is there a better way to use `WIFI` for `IPS`?

Comment: Interesting project. Any success or updates?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We had to put it on hold for a big project and then the summer holiday came and then there were  other projects so now I have 10 Qualcomm Atheros AR938x WIFI adapters laying around in a box gathering dust. I guess we've all been there.

Comment: If I remember correctly we did eventually got the WIFI data and could store it in a database. We never got around to actually converting the data to a location. I believe there was another flag we needed to use to gather more data.

Comment: I see. Perhaps simple routers (or WiFi dongles) don't change their power output. In addition, if in monitor mode, it might remain static (as to yuor setting). So if signal strength doesn't change it may not output. But why are you using packet capture to get the signal strength and not iwconfig etc?